# How do I delete an entry from Firefox's address bar autocomplete?

Tags: firefox

Delete does not work, shift+delete does not work. It's frustrating to have old misspelled addresses constantly pop up and have no way to remove them. I constantly go to the wrong pages.

Windows 7.

Comment: Are the misspelled addresses genuine addresses (i.e. can resolve and be displayed, just not the website you want), or not?

Comment: Try to add the version of firefox you are using... maybe it changes the behavior. BTW if you click on the bar, select the url you want to delete and press the left shift and del it deletes the selected address.  (Firefox 80 under Linux).

Answer (score 3):

1. Click the "View history, saved bookmarks, and more" button (i.e., the button with an icon featuring books standing side by side).
2. Click the "History" menu item in the menu that appears.
3. Click the "Show All History" button at the bottom of the new menu that appears.
4. In the "Library" window that appears, search for each relevant history item, right-click the history item, and select the "Delete Page" menu item in the shortcut menu.

Tested in Firefox 80.0 in Windows 10.

Comment: There's currently an additional menu item "Forget about this site" next to "Delete Page", which seems to remove all related pages at once.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the delete function fail as well and came up with this solution:

- Locate your browser profile folder (e.g. .mozilla/firefox/somerandomstring.default)
- locate the file `places.sqlite`
- Open it with a tool, that can handle SQlite V3 databases (e.g. the `sqlite3` command line utility)
- Use the SQL `SELECT id, url FROM moz_places WHERE url LIKE '%xxxx%';` (with "xxxx" replaced by your typo) to locate the unwanted line and note the `id`column (an integer)
- Use the SQL `DELETE FROM moz_places WHERE id=xxxx;` (with xxxx replaced by the id value from above) to get rid of the line

Comment: I recommended sqlitespy https://www.yunqa.de/delphi/products/sqlitespy/index

Answer (score 0):

It took me over an hour to figure out but it worked by doing this:

Go to Options-Home.
In the 'Firefox Home Content' section, check Top Sites.

Open a new tab.

You should see a bunch icons below the search bar.

Hover over the site you don't want and click the 3 dots that appear .
Click Dismiss.

The site should now be gone from the address bar.

EDIT: They've removed Top Sites and replaced it with a Shortcuts checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl+h</kbd> to open the history pane.
2. Set **Search history** to the web site name to delete (e.g., `cnn.com`).
3. Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> twice to navigate out of the input field and onto the hyperlinks.
4. Press <kbd>Down</kbd> then <kbd>Up</kbd> to select the first item.
5. Press <kbd>Shift+End</kbd> to select all items.
6. Press <kbd>Del</kbd> to delete them all.
7. Press <kbd>Ctrl+h</kbd> to hide the history pane.

Then try it out:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl+l</kbd> to navigate to the location bar.
2. Type: `cnn.com`

The website is vanquished.

Answer (score 0):

The suggestions also come from your bookmarks.

Delete it from bookmarks, if you find it is there, or it will never go away.

Press `<shift><ctrl>o` to bring up the bookmarks manager. Search for the offending url and simply delete it.