# how do I delete an autocomplete suggestion in firefox macos

Tags: firefox, autocomplete

I use Cyberchef quite often, not often enough to have a visible bookmark on the useless bar. So I often go to the search bar and type in `cyb` and hit `downarrow` and `enter`.

[image]

But at some unknown point the first entry became 'nixCraft' and I'd like to know how, on macos, on firefox 111 or above, I can remove this auto suggested entry so that it's not there at the top. I don't seem to have any control over auto-complete entries at all.

I do not knowingly have a bookmark for this site, but I do have about 10,000 bookmarks in about 500 folders going back 20-odd years so it could be hiding in there somewhere. I've exhaustively searched. I've exported my bookmarks and text searched. It. Is. Not. There.

It is not in my history at all, not recent history, not ancient history. I searched everything. It's. Not. In. My. History.

But it always shows up first.

Any answers that state I need to "shift-delete" or "select with arrow keys" all *do not work*. Every suggestion I've seen talks about how pressing delete "worked for them". It does not "work for me", probably because I am on macos and they were presumably on Windows.

Tried [Remove suggestion from Firefox autocomplete in URL input field](https://superuser.com/questions/1755870/remove-suggestion-from-firefox-autocomplete-in-url-input-field)

Tried [How do I delete an entry from Firefox's address bar autocomplete?](https://superuser.com/questions/1539314/how-do-i-delete-an-entry-from-firefoxs-address-bar-autocomplete)

Tried https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/remove-websites-address-bar-suggestions

Tried https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/address-bar-autocomplete-firefox

Tried numerous equally useless https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WLQMrz3GiVM youtube videos.

Comment: Have you checked it's not a bookmark? In Safari, it could be hiding in this list too - https://i.stack.imgur.com/FF12a.jpg - idk about FF

Comment: Yes, I also checked saved website data.